# R slow assignment in setRefClass

Tags: r, performance

Perhaps this question should be in some programming forum, but I thought I would ask it in the statistics community. The following code illustrates the problem when performing global assignment in R's setRefClass:

```
class <- setRefClass("class", 
  fields = list(
    params = "numeric"
  ),
  methods = list(
    initialize = function() {
      params <<- 5
    }, 
    do.stuff = function() {      
      for (i in 1:1e5)
        params <<- 2
    }
))

# FAST:
params <- 5
time <- Sys.time(); for (i in 1:1e5) params <- 2; time <- Sys.time() - time
print(time)

# SLOW:
newclass <- class$new()
time <- Sys.time(); newclass$do.stuff(); time <- Sys.time() - time
print(time)
```

And pqR shows a slight improvement in runtime, but nothing drastic.

I would like to know why this is happening... in my mind, assigning a variable should be fast. Maybe this has something to do with locating an object "slot" (variable location), similar to S3/S4 classes. I bet I can only observe such behavior with R, and not C++.

Comment: Perhaps due to the difference between "<-" and "<<-"?

Comment: But how would one set public class variable values without the "<<-"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As defined, an error check will be done on each assignment to "params" to ensure that only "numeric" data is stored there.  It goes faster if the definition is changed from fields = list(params = "numeric") to just fields="params".